# Unable to change CSS font classes

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

is the start of a website i'm making for a client
http://www.designobvio.us/smartklubben/

Heres the problem. I started the project a while ago and now am coming back, **I cannot seem to change font styles at all..** unless i use inline styles.

I used html5boilerplate.  Does anyone know what the hell is limiiting my font styles from being able to be styled outside of inline styling?

For example, `#footer p{color:#fff;}` will not change

Comment: you should show us how you're trying to change the font (which selector are you trying on which element) and any other relevant styles.

Comment: you cannot change p, h1,h2 at all. they are all set.  if i go to style.css and put in h1{font-size: 12px; color:blue} nothing works.

Comment: #footer p{color:#fff;} will not change

Comment: please include relevant code *inside* your answer, you can edit it.

Comment: @MatthewHarwood works fine for me through inspector http://grab.by/bUl4.

Comment: no css styles can be applied to text unless they are inline.  Not even !important works.  I need a direct class, ID to change styles on the speific take.  e.g.  <p class="styleRed">I'm red text</p>  to style the paragraph red.

Comment: @matthew include the 'a' tag: #footer p a {color:#fff;}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have a problem with the *specificity* of the CSS rule.

Let's say you have 2 CSS rules, as follows:

```
.use-font { font-size: 24px; }
#content { font-size: 48px; }

<html><body>
  <div id="content">
    <p class="use-font">Hello!</p>
  </div>
</body></html>
```

You would expect the paragraph to use font size of 24px but it will use 48px instead.

This is because the selectors you use to define your rule have a priority. A class like `.use-font` counts as 10, an HTML entity like `h2` will count as 1, and an ID such as `#content` counts as 100. Since `.use-font` would equal 10 and `#content` equals 100, then the 48px rule will take precedence. The solution is to make the rule appear as

```
#content .use-font { ... }
```

That makes it worth 110 points, and thereby overriding the other defined rule.

More examples:

```
body { .. } = 1 points
#content ul.product-listing li a { ... } = 113 points
div.field-header label = 12 points
```

EDIT: Corrected my mistake in that tag selectors are worth 1 point while classes are worth 10, not the other way around. See more examples at http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 1):

I don't approve overuse of it but you could try with `!important`, as it usually suggests bad CSS design.

```
.myOtherClass{
     font-size: 36px !important;
}
```

EDIT: (according to your comment)

```
.myH1class{
    font-size: 20px; //this will be used, as class-styles have precedence over tag-styles (below)
}

h1{
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

solution: either write **more specific** class definition, or use `!important`

Comment: even important doesnt work as somethign to over write the css

Comment: Hmm, you should then update your question with HTML/CSS snippets, as we are shooting in a dark here ;)

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you take your font-face style out of the header? Does your font-change work then?

Answer (score 0):

Are you editing the right css file? I would suggest loading the website in a browser and checking the CSS file source code been loaded in the browser to see if your latest changes are present.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments to your question: `#footer p{color:#fff;}` will not change

Have you simply tried: `#footer p a {color:#fff;}`?

Answer (score 0):

The text in the footer paragraph looks white to me. Perhaps clear your cache? What does appear strange are the links in the footer, which are defined by your `a` and `a:visited` rules, not your `#footer p`. Try...

```
#footer p a,#footer p a:visited {
color: #fff;
}
```